# gdata youtube query problem

Tags: iphone, youtube-api, gdata-api

i have asked this question before but no answer was there. so asking again.

I just cant figure out which gdata framework class to use so that i can search youtube videos . i used some classes by debugging code but i think the framework is so deep that it can take a lot of time to figure out this problem . so please help me . i have a search box in my app and i want that after entering any keyword(s) in that search box and tapping the search button i should get the proper response . i tried some code but always it returns the same result.

here is my code...

```
-(void)searchYoutube
{

NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", searchField.text];

NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForFeedID:nil];


GDataQueryYouTube* query = [GDataQueryYouTube  youTubeQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
[query setStartIndex:1];
[query setMaxResults:50];

//[query setFullTextQueryString:searchString];
[query setVideoQuery:searchString];
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL                    delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];



 }
```

below is the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCellVideoList *cell = (CustomCellVideoList *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCellVideoList alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;




    // Configure the cell.
    GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
    NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup];
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [mediaGroup mediaDescription];
    GDataMediaTitle *mTtile = [mediaGroup mediaTitle];
    NSLog(@"media  group----- \n\n%@",[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup]);
    cell.videoTitle.text = [mTtile stringValue ] ;
    cell.videoDesc.text = [desc stringValue];

    // GDataMediaContent has the urls to play the video....

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thumbnails objectAtIndex:1] URLString]]];
    //cell.videoImgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.data = data;

}
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query object adds the query parameters onto the feed URL.

You can see the full query string with  NSLog(@"%@", [query URL])

Do the fetch with   [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query ...]
or the equivalent   [service fetchFeedWithURL:[query URL] ...]

Comment: ya  thanks grobbins finally i saw this mistake and now its showing the correct result .. thanks  very much